# Type mismatch: scala.xml.NodeBuffer vs Seq[scala.xml.Node]

Tags: xml, scala

I am running the following code

```
val x = <a>a</a>
```

and resulting in the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.xml.NodeBuffer
[error]  required: Seq[scala.xml.Node]
```

Comment: could you format the code, the snippet ```val x = <a>a</a>``` is executing fine and resulting in the following output ```x: scala.xml.Elem = <a>a</a>```

Comment: Scala 2:13.0, 2:13:2. Even:  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { <a>a</a>} could no be compiled. Type mismatch;
[error]  found   : scala.xml.NodeBuffer
[error]  required: Seq[scala.xml.Node]

Comment: I used scala 2.11.0

Comment: downvoting because that code compiles just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the jar file for scala.xml,then only it not gives the error.

Visit this link, to download the xml package for your scala version,

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml